# Get very high-resolution map of country borders map

Tags: svg, maps, screenshot

Sorry if that question is not about programming, but it still about development.
I have very big problem. I have project where is very detailed map of countries is used, so i need to make high-detailed SVGs of that countries. I tried to do detailed screenshots of google maps and "connect" them by mouse, then make SVG path over them, and it first is was okay. But more screenshots i made, more problems i had. I don't know where to find very high detailed background, to draw SVGs over it. And also i need all SVGs to use same point coordinates, so variants like getting SVGs from downloading somewhere is bad. [Here what I was doing, it took 4 weeks and it will be sad to delete that result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr6sv.jpg)

Comment: Just letting you know that you can get an svg of Balcans here: https://d-maps.com/pays.php?num_pay=181&lang=en

Comment: @enxaneta, thanks, but I need full world map in very good resolution. I tried to make it from screenshots of Google Maps, but i got places where the screenshots are unjoinable, and thats terrible

Comment: Any way you can use https://www.openstreetmap.org/ to solve your problem?

Comment: Or maybe this: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/

Comment: Your topic is interesting to me, but I don't have that much experience in this.  So searching around and found this page that talks about using QGIS to export a map as SVG: https://www.igismap.com/qgis-3-2-1-download-export-map-in-pdf-svg-image/

Comment: I think OpenStreetMap may be better quality, and here is an interesting video: [Inkscape - Custom SVG Maps from OpenStreetMap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_v7HrDJfyk)

Comment: Here you have the whole world: https://d-maps.com/continent.php?num_con=8&lang=en

Comment: @Darin I can use OSM, but i don`t see any pros in it

Comment: @enxaneta unfortunately, the resolution is quite small :(